# Affer change package name, have error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo"{} java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, package

I'm having problems after renaming package name, 
I checked the package name in the file and it Manifes true, than i get this error message

```
03-31 10:07:53.834: E/AndroidRuntime(17981): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{org.example.touch/edu.dongthang.screens.SplashScreen}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and this is SplashScreens

```
package edu.dongthang.screens;

import edu.dongthang.screens.R;
import java.util.Locale;
import edu.dongthang.screens.MainMenu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity{
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;
SettingScreen st;
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor editor;
public String lang;
Configuration config1;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = pref.edit();
    lang = pref.getString("language", null).toString();
    Locale la = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(la);
    //updateResourse();
    config1 = new Configuration();
    config1.locale = la;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config1,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //refresh();
    Toast.makeText(this, "ngon ngu la "+lang, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}

}
```

and file Manifast

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.dongthang.screens"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name="edu.dongthang.controller.AppDelegate"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="edu.dongthang.controller.Controller" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="edu.dongthang.screens.MainMenu" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="edu.dongthang.controller.Touch" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="edu.dongthang.screens.SettingScreen" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

</manifest>
```

Please, help me solve this problem, thank so much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the activity name always like this so you change main activity name into like this..

```
edu.dongthang.controller.//package Name with actiivty name in your main activity...
 //replace the .Splashacreen activity name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Where did you store the value for **language** in `SharedPreferences`

Without storing in `SharedPreferences` if you get that value you will return **null**

```
lang = pref.getString("language", null).toString();
```

In that above line **lang** value is **null** then you are using that in below line so you will get **NPE** try to store that value and try.

```
Locale la = new Locale(lang);
```

Comment: @user2028608 if my ans really helpful ple accept it.